# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles') discord js

Tags: javascript

Код

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(reaction)
    console.log()
    console.log(user)
    console.log()
    console.log(reactions[`${reaction.message.guildId}`])
    console.log(reactions[`${reaction.message.guildId}`][`${reaction.message.id}`])
    console.log(reaction.emoji.name)
    if (reaction.emoji.name in reactions[`${reaction.message.guildId}`][`${reaction.message.id}`]) {
        console.log(1)
        let roleId = reaction.name in reactions[`${reaction.message.guildId}`][`${reaction.message.id}`]
        let role = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === `${roleId}`)

        const member = reaction.message.mentions.members.first()
        try {
            member.roles.add(role);
        } catch(error) {
            reaction.message.channel.send(`${error}`);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ошибка значит, что читать то и нечего, то что ты пытаешься прочитать там ничего не лежит, может не инициализировал или еще что. В любом случае нужен какой-то контекст. Подробнее опиши проблему.